# Why awk convert exponential to normal integer?

Tags: bash, awk

This may be a very basic question about **awk** to handle **exponential**.

My input line is:

```
1.047788047990001417e+02 2.931134551062188009e+01 3.669999999999999929e+00
```

I want to add -1000 at third position but in exponential format, so first I convert the format.

```
dept=$(echo -1000 | awk '{printf "%.7e\n", $1}')
```

But when I try to insert it into the above line using **cat** and **awk**, it converts back to normal integers.

```
cat $line | awk '{print $1 ,$2 ,'$dept', $3}'
```

I got this output:

```
1.048020560949027811e+02 2.976214868620721887e+01 -1000 6.065999999999999837e+00
```

May you please indicate that where I am doing something wrong or how I can correct it?
Besides this, is there any option to limit the 7 decimal numbers before **e**?

For example **ideally** expected output should be like this:

```
1.0480205e+02 2.9762148e+01 -1.0000000e+03 6.0659999e+00
```

Comment: Because integers are printed as integers by default, exponential notation is only used for floating point.

Comment: BTW, `$line` is not necessary for the question. You can demonstrate the problem with `echo '' | awk '{print -1.0000000e+03}'`

Comment: Right @Barmar i used the line because I need to handle lot of rows from a file,. For integer, actually it requires a format so I was trying to follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers are printed as integers by default, even if you input it with exponential notation. If you want it formated, use `printf()`.

```
cat "$line" | awk -v dept=-1.0000000e+03 '{printf("%e %e %e %e\n", $1, $2, dept, $3)}'
```

Use the `-v` option to turn a shell variable into an awk variable, rather than substituting the variable into the awk script.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line in `bash` (not `awk` yet):

```
cat $line | awk '{print $1 ,$2 ,'$dept', $3}'
```

Bash replaces the values in the unquoted parts of the line:

```
awk '{print $1 ,$2 ,'-1.0000000e+03', $3}'
```

then removes the quotes, and recognises "words":

```
$0=awk
$1={print $1 ,$2 ,-1.0000000e+03, $3}
```

Now you can see that `awk` treats `-1.0000000e+03` as a number, and it is not aware that there is any particular format it should stick to; it figures `-1000` is the easier way to represent that number and prints that.

To avoid that, you have to tell `awk` to treat `$dept` as a string — by including some extra quoting:

```
cat $line | awk '{print $1 ,$2 ,"'$dept'", $3}'
```

EDIT: This answer tells you exactly what is going on in your code; but you should use Barmar's answer, as it is much cleaner way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well if I convert it into string "'$dept'". May I just ask, how to round off decimal before **exponential**. I know it for normal case but not in this form.

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `print`, with `%.7e` as the format specifier for all four output fields. Better yet, use Barmar's code.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?

```
echo '1.047788047990001417e+02
      2.931134551062188009e+01
      3.669999999999999929e+00' \
 \
 | mawk 'NF+=($_=sprintf("%.*e %.*e %.*e %.*e",
                 __=-(++_)+(++_^++_),$(_+=-_++),__,
                    $++_,__,-(++_+__)^_,__,$_))~""'

1.0477880e+02 2.9311346e+01 -1.0000000e+03 3.6700000e+00
```